# Blocking with Task?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task, async-ctp

I try to use tasks in my application like this :

```
Task test;
test = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => general.Login(loginName, password));
MyTextBox.Text = "test text";
```

It will be the UI thread that makes this call and I need it to be blocked until the worker thread returns from the service but I do not want the UI to freeze.

I could use a ContinueWith but this will split my login method and this makes it harder to follow. I do also need the main UI thread to run the rest of the code in this method.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Use the Async-CTP or wait for C# 5.

Comment: If the UI thread blocks then the UI freezes.  Do you want to show a modal form while waiting for the task to finish?

Comment: @CodeInChaos > could you pleas provide some more information about C# 5 on this problem?

Comment: The async-await C# feature allows you to write continuation based code in a way that looks like normal code. And to get this feature you need either the async CTP, or C# 5. Just look at the website Jon linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is precisely the problem that async in C# 5 solves. For the moment, you basically have to split your code. It's a pain, but that's the way it is. (Your description is slightly off, by the way - you *don't* want to block the UI thread... you want to "not perform the second part of your logic" until the worker thread returns. Not quite the same thing :) (You may also want to disable some other bits of the UI, but we can't tell for sure.)

It's worth getting a head start on the async feature - see the [Visual Studio async home page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) for a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to wait for a thread without blocking the waiting thread. What you can do is something like:

```
fire task
do some other task
wait for task  // hopefully the task finished by now
```